# Some Junit5 test codes are not run

Tags: android, junit, junit5, parameterized-unit-test

I am developing an android with Junit5 and Mockito.

Some tests are `ParameterizedTest` and others are just `Test`.

Here is my sample code.

When I run this test, only "ParameterizedTests" run.

"JustTests" is not shown on the JUnit test console list.

How can I run "JustTests" too?

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource
import org.mockito.InOrder
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.Mockito.*
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations

internal class MyPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var view: MyContract.View

    private lateinit var presenter: MyContract.Presenter

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
        presenter = MyPresenter(view)
    }


    @Nested
    @DisplayName("Just Test")
    inner class JustTests {

        @DisplayName("test 1")
        @Test
        fun greetingTest1() {
           ...
        }

    }
    
    @Nested
    @DisplayName("Parameterized test")
    inner class ParameterizedTests {

        @ParameterizedTest(name = "{0}")
        @ValueSource(strings = ["Hello", "Hi])
        @Test
        fun greetingTest2(greeting: String) {
            ...
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your imports?

Comment: @johanneslink I added imports.

Comment: should I use "org.junit.jupiter.api.Test" intead of "org.junit.Test"?

Comment: Exactly. This should fix it.